# .NET performance tuning

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, 64-bit, performance-testing

My .Net application is a 4.0 ASP.net app with alot of database updates, and grid refreshes upon grid refresh certain events that execute to update tables etc.) Question is... What would you surmise as 'eating alot of ram' in my application. (it grows to over 1gb easily within a few minutes)...

How would I tackle this?? What type of optimization would I be seeking? or what would you think would best suite me in regards to a proper approach?

This has been bugging me a while, but I can't for the life of me figure out whats causing the bottleneck.  I've closed my objects, etc. But unsure if the bottleneck is in the SQL or ASP.net backend.

Comment: How do you update/insert to DB? I mean you are updating one record by one transaction? Please provide a bit more detail.. data update process..or any code that we can check..

Comment: @jason how are you populating the grids? Are you using datasets? Are you storing said datasets in sessions? how did you code the data retrieval for the grids? Are you only returning the data necessary for the current page or are you returning all xxx rows just to show 100 of them? There's so many places to look for issues

Answer (score 2):

Could be anything.

The tools for debugging this type of issue are called memory profilers. There's a good one called ".NET Memory Profiler" (see memprofiler.com) that has a free trial. Some versions of Visual Studio also include a memory profiler.

As a guess, I'd say you're saving some data-containing object in a static variable somewhere, and not releasing it when you're done using it.

Comment: This made me think, I will check ALL objects independently to check if everything is released. (=Nothing) at the end of their routines. It's very possible, thinkin of shared variables I never checked those... I will let everyone know.

Answer (score 0):

**Below are my opinions**

> My .Net application is a 4.0 ASP.net app with alot of database updates

**Using statements for ADO.Net**

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Your Stored Procedure Name", con))
    {
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "Parameter Name";
        param.Value = "Value";
        param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

---

> and grid refreshes upon grid refresh certain events that execute to
>   update tables etc.

1. Keep your records in your grid using paging...to avoid Performance/Memory Management Issues
2. Once the grid is to repopulate, dispose it before binding data.

---

> What would you surmise as 'eating alot of ram' in my application. (it
>   grows to over 1gb easily within a few minutes)...

Are you using DataSet/DataTable ? Please dispose it once used. Otherwise you will face `Memory Out of Exception` crash...

---

You can use ANTS MEMORY PROFILER for the memory leaks

**Reference**

[**ANTS MEMORY PROFILER**](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)

Comment: To answer a few questions, SqlDataSource is my "data source" im using parameterized queries for updates. Would that be faster to make a stored procedure for the queries versus using parameterized select queries?? They are simply one liner (SET [field] = @newvalue) type of queries. But over a growing database (currently only 300 rows but expectation over 10000 and if we're having memory issues now, we definitely want that resolved before we move forward.

Comment: I will check the ANTS out, Ive heard of it, never used it; is it fairly easy to implement to profile an asp.net app?

Comment: -1 for ants ;) Been there, used it - Scitech is a LOT better ;) Sorry, I like their products in general... Scitech memory profiler, visual studio performance profiler and you areh appyn.